# How to get the current Nodes where the Job is running

Tags: rundeck

I'm developing a job and the user can choose in which nodes can run, so the Node Filter is open to the convenient of the user.

When the job is starting I need to do a calculation based in the number of nodes chosed by the user, exist a way to get this number?

Regards,

Alejandro L

Answer (score 1):

By design, that information is only available after the execution, so, a good approach is to call the job [via API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#running-a-job) (in a script step) and with the execution ID number (available in the API call output) you can list and count the nodes, e.g:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

nodes=$(curl -s -X GET "http://localhost:4440/api/41/execution/16" \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: your_user_token" \
 | jq -r '.successfulNodes | . []')

number_of_nodes=$(echo $nodes | wc -w)

echo "Number of nodes: $number_of_nodes"
```

This example needs [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to extract the nodes from the API response.

Anyway, your request sounds good for an enhancement request, please suggest that [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I going to create the idea to improve the tool, currently I'm trying this with Rundeck 4.1.0 and after create the token the API never return a JSON with the section successfulNodes, this query work in this version?

Comment: Yeah, it works on 4.1.0, tested using Thunder Client: https://imgur.com/U1Bbki8

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  it happens when the job finished, no when is running, but I need the information almost when the job is starting, any work around?

Comment: Another way is to run the job using the filter parameter with all jobs defined individually (like this: https://imgur.com/LPcNhpF), but this doesn't work if you want to use regex filters like `node.*` or just `.*`. You can create a script that get those nodes, count them and pass them as an option value.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround to take would be using [job.filter](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#context-variables) variable

so if you do `@job.filter@`

it returns a string with the list of nodes like `us-east-1-0,us-east-1-1,us-east-1-2`

if you save it as a string, and then split the string on `','` then you get an array of nodes:

`IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$string"`

and then you can get the number of nodes by
`echo ${#array[@]}`

##### Note

as @MegaDrive68k mentioned this won't work if use select all node with the use of filter `.*`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old question but I can tell how I solved a similar requirement in Rundeck version 4.17. *Note*: maybe it does not fit your need exactly but maybe it will help someone.

I needed to run a Workflow locally, but the user should be able to select specific Nodes as targets. So I added some Workflow steps but configured the job to be dispatched to Nodes. This configuration enables the user to select Nodes from Rundeck inventory but the Workflow steps are run locally on the same server. In one (or several) of the steps I needed to get all the nodes the user selected, and I used *job.filter* variable to get the names. This worked well *but* as @Sergey and @MegaDrive68k noted, this doesn't work when target nodes are selected with a filter as *.** or a tag. Sure you can then call the API from a script via *curl* as @MegaDrive68k explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72604628/23660103) or run *rd* command line tool to query the API for the nodes matching the used filter, but if you add a Node Step with a Remote Command or Inline Script you can set a global variable and then on your Workflow Steps you can get access to it.
Node Steps run *before* the workflow steps, so:

1. Add as first step a Run Remote Command Node Step or Run Inline Script Node Step.
2. Echo the node name or hostname with a pattern to capture it later:

- For Run Remote Command: `echo "RUNDECK:DATA:MY_NODES=${node.hostname}"`
- For Run Inline Script: `echo "RUNDECK:DATA:MY_NODES=@node.hostname@"`

3. Add a Key Value Data Log Filter for this step (with default regex pattern). You will get a variable named MY_NODES inside *data* context.
4. Edit the Workflow Step script that needs the nodes list and get the value for all the nodes: `mySelectedNodes=${data.MY_NODES*}`. It will get all the values for all the nodes concatenated with comma.
5. Now you can work with this list, split it or pass it to some other script or step, read as an array as [@Sergey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660726/23660103) commented, etc.

The problem with this approach is that if a Node can't be reached then you will not know if it was part of the targets selected by the user, given that the Node steps have to be run on the unreachable node and therefore you won't get it's name/hostname

Maybe it's not the more elegant solution, but I hope it will help someone.